# diferencia entre [][] y [,] en matrices multidimensionales en c#

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber si alguien sabe cual es la diferencia entre estas dos formas de declarar matrices multidimensionales en `c#`.

```
string[][] m = new string[2][]; // primera forma

string[,] m2 = new string[2, 2]; // segunda forma
```

Y porque cuando lo declaro de la siguiente manera:

```
string[][] m = new string[2][2]; // <- me marca un error
```

Me marca un error al asignarle la segunda longitud entre el segundo par de corchetes.

> como nota quiero mencionar que siempre los e declaro de la segunda forma mencionada en primer bloque de codigo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una es una matriz de matrices, y la otra es un array 2d.

Es decir, un doble [] [] puede ser valido así:

```
string [] [] matriz = new string [5] [];

matriz [0] = new string [7];
matriz [1] = new string [1];
matriz [2] = new string [666];
matriz [3] = new string [3];
matriz [4] = new string [2];
```

Debido a que cada entrada de la matriz es una referencia a otra matriz de string. De forma escalonada, se puede hacer una asignación a una matriz como lo haces con la segunda forma.

Otra diferencia importante es que la matriz 2d es uniforme, y por tanto no se puede asignar una matriz 1d a una fila o columna. Es decir, que por obligación tienes que darle el índice de la fila y de la columna.

Espero haber resuelto tu duda.